# How to pass query url parameter to a twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, drupal-8

I am trying to pass query string parameters through my url to a node twig template (node--template.html.twig) I have tried

```
 {% set queryParams = app.request.query.all %}
```

However, nothing is showing when passed.

Comment: Did you clean cache?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.

```
 {% set queryParams = app.request.query.all %}
```

This statement will not show anything. Because it is only supposed to assign query variables array to `queryParams`

If you want to display, you have multiple ways after the above statement.

For example, if you just want to display the value of user_id query variable from URL.

```
{% set queryParams = app.request.query.all %}
{{ queryParams["user_id"] }}
```

Another example, if you want to loop through all query variables:

```
{% set queryParams = app.request.query.all %}
{% for key, value in queryParams %}
    {{ key }} => {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Drupal.  There is no "app" object available in twig templates.

Comment: @arnoldbird I have not used Drupal but I think this will help you. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217784/how-to-retrieve-get-parameter-in-twig-template